# Query of load csv not completing even after 12 hours

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have been using Neo4j for quite a while now. I ran this query earlier before my computer crashed 7 days ago and somehow unable to run it now. I need to create a graph database out of a csv of bank transactions. The original dataset has around 5 million rows and has around 60 columns.

This is the query I used, starting from 'Export CSV from real data' [demo](https://github.com/nicolewhite/neo4j-complaints/blob/master/load.cql) by Nicole White:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Transactions_with_risk_scores.csv" AS line
WITH DISTINCT line, SPLIT(line.VALUE_DATE, "/") AS date
WHERE line.TRANSACTION_ID IS NOT NULL AND line.VALUE_DATE IS NOT NULL
MERGE (transaction:Transaction {id:line.TRANSACTION_ID})
SET transaction.base_currency_amount =toInteger(line.AMOUNT_IN_BASE_CURRENCY),
transaction.base_currency = line.BASE_CURRENCY,
transaction.cd_code = line.CREDIT_DEBIT_CODE,
transaction.txn_type_code = line.TRANSACTION_TYPE_CODE,
transaction.instrument = line.INSTRUMENT,
transaction.region= line.REGION,
transaction.scope = line.SCOPE,
transaction.COUNTRY_RISK_SCORE= line.COUNTRY_RISK_SCORE,
transaction.year = toInteger(date[2]),
transaction.month = toInteger(date[1]),
transaction.day = toInteger(date[0]);
```

I tried:

1. Using LIMIT 0 before running query as per Micheal Hunger's suggestion in a post about 'Loading Large datasets'.
2. Used single MERGE per statement (this is first merge and there are 4 other merges to be used) as suggested by Michael again in another [post](https://neo4j.com/blog/bulk-data-import-neo4j-3-0/).
3. Tried CALL apoc.periodic.iterate and apoc.cypher.parallel but doesn't work with LOAD CSV (seem to work only with MERGE and CREATE queries without LOAD CSV).
   I get following error with  CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(""):
   Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'f': expected whitespace, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', '~', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ')' (line 2, column 29 (offset: 57))
4. Increased max heap size to 16G as my laptop is of 16GB RAM. Btw finding it difficult to write this post as I tried running again now with 'PROFILE ' and it is still running since an hour.

Help needed to load query of this 5 million rows dataset. Any help would highly be appreciated.Thanks in advance! I am using Neo4j 3.5.1 on PC.

Comment: Can you add the output of the `:schema` command along in your question, so we have a view on your index to evaluate

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen currently running the query, will output schema after I give up on it.

Comment: 3. currently it's a syntax error but  you may get null pointer later if run MERGE in parallel

Comment: You are using  MERGE then why are you using DISTINCT? I am not sure if it's causing any issues, still curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **MOST IMPORTANT:** Create **Index/Constraint** on the key property.

> CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (t:Transaction) ASSERT t.id IS UNIQUE;

2. Don't set the max heap size to full of system RAM. Set it to **50%**.
3. Try **ON CREATE SET** instead of **SET**.
4. You can also use ***apoc.periodic.iterate*** to load the data, but **USING PERIODIC COMMIT** is also fine.
5. Importantly, if you are 'USING PERIODIC COMMIT' and the query is not finishing or running out of memory, it is likely because of using Distinct. Avoid Distinct as duplicate transactions will be handled by MERGE.

**NOTE:** (If you use **apoc.periodic.iterate**  to MERGE nodes/relationships with parameter **parallel=true** then it fails with NULL POINTER EXCEPTION. use it carefully)

Questioner edit: Removing Distinct in 3rd line for Transaction node and re-running the query worked!

Comment: Thanks for your answer:
1. but constraint was already created.
3. Tried ON CREATE SET prior to SET.
2. Will try that, thanks.
4. CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("<above query>") doesn't work even without 'USING PERIODIC COMMIT'. In all examples for apoc.periodic.iterate, I only see it with MERGE or CREATE statements directly and not with LOAD CSV as is the case here. Any idea on what could be wrong with this error? Error illustrated in the edit of the question under point 3 of 'I tried'. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are setting max heap size to 8GB, You can increase the PERIODIC LIMIT to 10000.

Comment: You can also use Halin to monitor the heap usage etc: https://github.com/moxious/halin

Comment: btw I have max heap size at 8GB  currently and is still now completing since 2 hours. So I don't think that helps.

Comment: Can you check in the browser how much data is loaded at this time?

Comment: No, it is just loading and on the Neo4j Desktop app/My project/Graph db - I just see 0 nodes and 0 relationships created. Is that the way to know how much data is loaded or is there a better way?

Comment: Oh by the time being, I finally got out of memory error for the task which ran for 2 hours: Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError: There is not enough memory to perform the current task

Comment: This should not happen with USING PERIODIC COMMIT, can you try removing DISTINCT on 3rd line. Monitor the heap usage with Halin.

Comment: Works without Distinct. That was the key, I think if you also edit that part in your answer, I will accept it as right answer. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186868/discussion-between-raj-and-bharat-ram-ammu).