# Cypher Import from CSV to Neo4J - How To Improve Performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am importing the following to Neo4J:

categories.csv

```
CategoryName1
CategoryName2
CategoryName3
...
```

categories_relations.csv

```
category_parent   category_child
CategoryName3     CategoryName10
CategoryName32    CategoryName41
...
```

Basically, categories_relations.csv shows parent-child relationships between the categories from categories.csv.

I imported the first csv file with the following query which went well and pretty quickly:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
 LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///categories.csv' as line
 CREATE (:Category {name:line[0]})
```

Then I imported the second csv file with:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///categories_relations.csv' as line
MATCH (a:Category),(b:Category)
WHERE a.name = line[0] AND b.name = line[1]
CREATE (a)-[r:ISPARENTOF]->(b)
```

I have about 2 million nodes.

I tried executing the 2nd query and it is taking quite long. Can I make the query execute more quickly?

Answer (score 1):

> **Confirm you are matching on right property.** You are setting only one property for **`Category`** node i.e. **`name`** while creating
>   categories. But you are matching on property **`id`** in your second
>   query to create the relationships between categories.

For executing the 2nd query faster you can **add an index on the property (here `id`)** which you are matching Category nodes on.

`CREATE INDEX ON :Category(id)`

***If it still takes time, You can refer my answer to Load CSV [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54236141/6077914)***

Comment: You are using `CREATE` for creating relationships so you need to delete all the relationships you created earlier

Comment: **You may get out of memory error, so increase the heap memory in neo4j.conf file**